# How to change the selected option to default when another select-option changes?

Tags: blazor

```
@inject IAccessData _db

<select @onchange="LoadSupplierType">
   <option value="0">Select Supplier</option>

   @foreach (var supplier in ProjectSuppliers)
    {
        <option value="@supplier.SupplierId">@supplier.SupplierName</option>
    }
</select>
<select @bind="Project.SupplierType">
   <option>Select Supplier type</option>

   @foreach (var type in SupplierTypes)
    {
        <option value="@type.SupplierTypeName">@type.SupplierTypeName</option>
    }
</select>

@code{
private ProjectModel Project;
private List<ProjectSuppliersModel> ProjectSuppliers;
private List<SupplierTypesModel> SupplierTypes;
private int supplierId = 1;

public void CreateProject()
{
    //a function to insert the current project in the database
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    ProjectSuppliers = _db.GetProjectSuppliers();
    SupplierTypes = _db.GetSupplierTypes(supplierId);
}

public void LoadSupplierType(ChangeEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if(SupplierTypes is not null)
        {
            SupplierTypes.Clear();
        }

        int newValue= Int32.Parse(eventArgs.Value.ToString());

        if(newValue!= 0)
        {
            SupplierId = newValue;
            Project.Supplier = _db.GetSupplierById(SupplierId).Supplier;
            SupplierTypes = _db.GetSupplierTypes(SupplierId);
        }        
    }
```

What should I do to reset the select element which has SupplierTypes(as its loop) to its first option("Select Supplier type") when I change the selection in the select element which has ProjectSuppliers (as its loop)?

Comment: Looking at my answer to your previous question, and now Brian Parker's answer to this one, I'm hoping that you'll really work some of this stuff out in your head: you can see some similar technique, and that's no accident.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I'm a beginner in this field. I didn't get how suppliers and supplierTypes are fetched from database in Brain Parker's answer?

Comment: In the previous question I preferred to use @onchange to do both of setting value to Project.Supplier and fetching data from database to set the list of supplierTypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to keep an actual class variable to store selected OBJECT rather than tracking the selected ID as `int`.  That way, it's easy to use `null` checks to format in Blazor.  And when I want to use that object in the future, I don't have to look anything up-- it's already set.

```
@page "/dropdown"

@if (SupplierTypes is not null)
{
    <select @onchange="HandleSupplierTypeChange">
        @if (SelectedSupplierType is null)
        {
            <option disabled selected>Select supplier type</option>
        }
        @foreach (var item in SupplierTypes)
        {
            <option value="@item.ID">@item.TypeName</option>
        }
    </select>
    <br />
}
@if (LoadedSuppliers is not null)
{
    <select @onchange="HandleSupplierChange">

        @if (SelectedSupplier is null)
        {
            <option selected disabled>Select a supplier</option>
        }
        @foreach (var item in LoadedSuppliers)
        {
            <option value="@item.ID">@item.SupplierName</option>
        }
    </select>
}

@code {
    class SupplierType
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
    }
    class Supplier
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SupplierTypeID { get; set; }
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    }
    List<SupplierType> SupplierTypes { get; set; }
    List<Supplier> AllSuppliers { get; set; }  
    List<Supplier> LoadedSuppliers { get; set; }  results
    SupplierType SelectedSupplierType { get; set; } // *** Note THIS! ***
    Supplier SelectedSupplier { get; set; } // *** Note THIS! ***

    async Task HandleSupplierTypeChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        int selectedID = Convert.ToInt32(args.Value.ToString());
        SelectedSupplierType = SupplierTypes.Where(st => st.ID == selectedID).Single();
        LoadedSuppliers = await LoadSupplierList(SelectedSupplierType.ID);
    }
    async Task<List<Supplier>> LoadSupplierList(int NewTypeID)
    {
        // Ignore my code, this is where you do DB
        return AllSuppliers.Where(all => all.SupplierTypeID == NewTypeID).ToList();
    }
    async Task HandleSupplierChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        int selectedID = Convert.ToInt32(args.Value.ToString());
        SelectedSupplier = LoadedSuppliers.Where(ls => ls.ID == selectedID).Single();
        SelectedSupplierType = null;
        //Do other DB stuff for the selected supplier here
    }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // I'm hard-coding the load, but you use DB
        SupplierTypes = new List<SupplierType> {
            new SupplierType{ ID=1, TypeName="Raw Resources"},
            new SupplierType{ ID=2, TypeName="Wholesale parts"},
            new SupplierType{ ID=3, TypeName="Retail items"}
        };
        AllSuppliers = new List<Supplier> {
            new Supplier{ID=1, SupplierTypeID = 1,  SupplierName="OilInc"},
            new Supplier{ID=2, SupplierTypeID = 1, SupplierName="GlassCo"},
            new Supplier{ID=3, SupplierTypeID = 2, SupplierName="WashersRUs"},
            new Supplier{ID=4, SupplierTypeID = 2, SupplierName="ScrewsInc"},
            new Supplier{ID=5, SupplierTypeID = 3, SupplierName="Levike"},
            new Supplier{ID=6, SupplierTypeID = 3, SupplierName="ArmaniSassoon"}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: wow what a explanation! thanks a lot Bennyboy1973

Answer (score 1):

Use the setter of the selected supplier:

```
<select @bind="@SelectedSupplierId">
    <option value="0">Select a supplier</option>
    @foreach (var supplier in suppliers)
    {
        <option value="@supplier.Id">@supplier.SupplierName</option>
    }
</select>
<select @bind="@selectedSupplierTypeId">
    <option value="0">Select a supplier type</option>
    @foreach (var supplierType in supplierTypes)
    {
        <option value="@supplierType.Id">@supplierType.SupplierTypeName</option>
    }
</select>
@code {
    [Inject]
    private IAccessData _db { get; set; }
    private int selectedSupplierId;
    private int selectedSupplierTypeId;
    private IEnumerable<ProjectSuppliersModel> suppliers;
    private IEnumerable<SupplierTypesModel> supplierTypes;

    public int SelectedSupplierId
    {
        get => selectedSupplierId;
        set
        {
            if (selectedSupplierId == value) return;
            selectedSupplierId = value;
            supplierTypes = _db.GetSupplierTypes(selectedSupplierId);
            selectedSupplierTypeId = default;
        }
    }    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        selectedSupplierId = default;
        selectedSupplierTypeId = default;
        suppliers = _db.GetProjectSuppliers();
        supplierTypes = Array.Empty<SupplierTypesModel>();
    }
}
```

[BlazorRepl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QbOgarOa45Y0zI4c30)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand how you get suppliers and supplierTypes from database?

Comment: @HosseinHosseini I didnt I thought the questions main concern was setting the sub select to default on change. 
Change the Inumerable's to database queries. I just generated sample data. `SelectSupplierTypes` is already a query of `supplierTypes`

Comment: @HosseinHosseini I updated the answer to look more familiar for you. I moved the generated data to a mock.